# Window files not opening in TextEditor

Tags: java, swing

I have made a simple TextEditor using Java (swing). When I open my application and click JMenuItem open and select the file using JFileChooser  then it displays the contents of the file in JTextArea. The program will run smoothly.
But when I double click on any Window Files then the application will open but the text area will be empty even if the file is not empty.
How to solve it?

Comment: How to solve it? Some code will be a good start.

Comment: i just wanted to know if i have to pass command line arguments or something like this :)

Comment: only a hint will be enough so i didn't posted the code

Comment: What do you mean by "the application will open"? Do you mean you are clicking on an executable file, not a text file? If so, what would you expect to see in the text area? How are you filling the text area?

Comment: When I double click on any window files then my editor will open but will not display the contents of the file